# Mostrar estructura relacional de tablas DB2 con sql developer

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy trabajando en un entorno **`DB2`** usando Oracle SQL Developer, se que puedo encontrar la estructura de la una tabla usando:

```
SELECT * FROM Sysibm.syscolumns WHERE tbname = '[NOMBRE_TABLA]';
```

pero esto solamente me muestra las filas de la tabla y su informacion, pero no me da la informacion concreta de las filas que son claves foraneas, es decir, puedo saber **qué** filas son claves foraneas de este modo:

```
SELECT * FROM Sysibm.syscolumns WHERE tbname = '[NOMBRE_TABLA]' AND FOREIGNKEY='S';
```

pero no a que tablas apuntan.

**¿Como puedo mostrar la estructura relacional de una tabla con otras?**

---

He probado con estas soluciones, pero sin exito, (creo que) **porque son respuestas `Oracle` y no `DB2`**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729996/list-of-foreign-keys-and-the-tables-they-reference
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535990/oracle-get-foreign-keys/5536400#5536400
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_retrievecatinfoaboutforeignkeys.html
- http://www.dbatodba.com/db2/how-to-do/how-to-find-out-foreign-key-on-db2-tables

Answer (score 1):

En [db2](/questions/tagged/db2) (LUW) las relaciones entre tablas se encuentran en la vista [SYSCAT.REFERENCES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001057.html):

```
db2 describe table syscat.references

                                Data type                     Column
Column name                     schema    Data type name      Length     Scale Nulls
------------------------------- --------- ------------------- ---------- ----- ------
CONSTNAME                       SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    128     0 No
TABSCHEMA                       SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    128     0 No
TABNAME                         SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    128     0 No
OWNER                           SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    128     0 No
OWNERTYPE                       SYSIBM    CHARACTER                    1     0 No
REFKEYNAME                      SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    128     0 No
REFTABSCHEMA                    SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    128     0 No
REFTABNAME                      SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    128     0 No
COLCOUNT                        SYSIBM    SMALLINT                     2     0 No
DELETERULE                      SYSIBM    CHARACTER                    1     0 No
UPDATERULE                      SYSIBM    CHARACTER                    1     0 No
CREATE_TIME                     SYSIBM    TIMESTAMP                   10     6 No
FK_COLNAMES                     SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    640     0 No
PK_COLNAMES                     SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    640     0 No
DEFINER                         SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    128     0 No

  15 record(s) selected.
```

En este [articulo](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1301foreignkey/index.html) de IBM vienen varios ejemplos SQL:

```sql
select  substr(R.reftabschema,1,12) as P_Schema, substr(R.reftabname,1,12) as PARENT,
        substr(R.tabschema,1,12) as C_Schema, substr (R.tabname,1,12) as CHILD,
        substr(R.constname,1,12) as CONSTNAME, 
        substr(LISTAGG(C.colname,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C.colname),1,20) as FKCOLS 
from syscat.references R, syscat.keycoluse C 
where 
   R.constname=C.constname and 
   R.tabschema=C.tabschema and 
   R.tabname=C.tabname
group by R.reftabschema, R.reftabname, R.tabschema, R.tabname, R.constname;
```